# Measuring sea urchins, struggling with detection and accuracy in OpenCV and potentially looking for alternative method

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am a marine biology PhD candidate with minimal experience with Python. I need to measure the diameters a large number of urchins frequently which I would like to automate and improve accuracy(it's tricky to physically measure urchins).

I have been advised to use OpenCV and have been trying to get the code from this [pyimagesearch blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) post. I have not found it to be highly effective for 2 reasons:

1. Accuracy is unlikely to be high enough (based on a small sample size I have been able to get so far. This is eluded to in the blog post, which is not ideal for round objects.
2. I am also mostly picking up many incorrect/inappropriate frames (not sure about terminology, but see images for example). Basically, it not only picks up the full urchin but also various points on the urchins (100s of these points). I have tried to increase the kernel size but this has not caused any changes. I cannot find out how to fix this. [See these images for examples](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RPBN60oiAJFpjOSYvjg88nnbt32uA1TX?usp=sharing).

I am sure there is probably an easy fix for the frames (?), and I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. Furthermore, if there is a more accurate way of doing this I would also like to know.

We need to know the size of the urchins' shells and not the spines. Therefore ideally I would like to measure just the shell of the urchin and not the spines, but if I have to measure the spines as well I can just deduct a constant (average spine length for urchins of a given size) which is fine but would reduce accuracy further.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any chance of adding a better reference object than the white circle with a barcode (or, perhaps, several of them)? Detecting sea urchins on a picture like this would require a code snippet a bit bigger than a typical StackOverflow answer but is not impossible

Comment: please add pictures with nothing drawn on them, for experimenting -- basically, you need these things to contrast against the background. this black background should be usable already, if not optimal. give your subjects some illumination. I'd recommend light coming sideways, so it illuminates your subjects while hardly hitting the background at all.

Comment: @Marat Thanks, I could take more images with a better reference image but do you think it is the reference image is the issue? It detects that without any problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Here is a link with the images:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13vZ543urSasjUOjKyE-09ty2XQCvRbqu?usp=sharing.  I could try to illuminate from the side next time, but the issue is that I will need to do this for at least a 100 urchins in one image to be viable. If illuminating from the side I think they will case a shadow over each other

Comment: well, "side". needn't be exactly sunset, just anything that isn't noon... because that would reflect on the background, brightening it (which you don't want). also take care to keep water droplets and other noise off the background. and perhaps fix the camera's focus. in the latest pictures it seems to focus on somewhere between background and camera, putting the urchins out of focus. -- I find the new pics quite usable. just takes some morphology and done. you *should* make sure these little balls have some more clearance between each other. muffin tray?

Comment: oh I just noticed, you talk about their *shells*, and they're black... so I would indeed now recommend a *white background*, or light blue, which would also contrast against the spines.

Comment: Why reference objects are important: the surface the objects placed on is likely not orthogonal to the camera direction. This means that objects with the same physical size will have different angle size on the picture depending on their placement. To account for that, there should be at least two reference objects in opposite corners, with repeated marks placed at known distance in both in horizontal and vertical plane. Ideally, photos should be taken on a background similar to engineering paper - this will result in best measurements.

Comment: Hello Christoph and Marat, My apologies about not getting back sooner but have been busy with other experiments but I now have some time to focus on this again. I have got images with a white background: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OUtlNkCWLTZ2-i1YRC6rcpvk5VEgUtvq?usp=sharing. Unfortunately, I am still having the same issue where I cannot get the frames around the urchins (the frames are just randomly placed around the image. I have been trying to distort the images without success. The track bar function is currently not working on openCV. Any ideas on what to try?